Please teach me the explanation of this hadith?
Sunan Abu Daawood, Sunan An-Nasai, Sunan Ibn Maajah and Ibn Hibbaan the latter said it was a sound Hadeeth:

“Any woman who brings into a family a person child who is not one of them by legal lineage, she shall have no relation left with Allah and paradise will be forbidden for her.

I had asked ChatGPT for an explanation this is what it said -
Explanation of the Hadith:
The content of the hadith:
The hadith mentions a woman who brings a child into a family who is not legally or biologically related to the family. This may refer to cases where a woman falsely claims that a child is from her husband or family when the child is actually from another source or lineage.
The hadith states that such a woman would "have no relation left with Allah" and "Paradise will be forbidden for her."
This is a very strong condemnation. Let's break it down in detail:
The importance of lineage in Islam:
Lineage (nasab) is considered sacred in Islamic law. Maintaining the integrity of lineage is crucial because it has implications for inheritance, family rights, and societal order. Falsifying one's lineage disrupts the structure of society and violates the rights of the individuals involved. This is why Islam places great emphasis on maintaining the truth regarding one's ancestry.
The woman’s role in this act:
In this hadith, the woman is the one being addressed because historically, the mother is often the one who may have knowledge of or involvement in how the child is raised or identified within a family. Whether the child is biologically hers or not, the act of bringing a child into a family with a false claim of parentage is considered a severe breach of Islamic law.
"No relation left with Allah":
This phrase is understood as meaning that the woman who falsely claims a child as part of her family will be distanced from Allah’s mercy and forgiveness. It signifies that the act is so grave that it has spiritual consequences. In Islam, having a connection with Allah's mercy and grace is central to one's hope for salvation and entry into Paradise. The severing of this connection indicates the seriousness of the sin.
"Paradise will be forbidden for her":
This part of the hadith is a warning that such an act may lead to severe consequences in the Hereafter, including being barred from entering Paradise. This is a strong deterrent aimed at preventing people from falsifying lineage, as the punishment could involve exclusion from Allah's mercy in the Hereafter.
Why Is Falsifying Lineage So Serious?
Rights of the child:
In Islamic society, the biological lineage of a child is critical. The child has rights tied to their biological parents, such as inheritance rights and the right to know their family history. Altering this lineage denies the child their rightful identity and the legal privileges that come with it.
Social order:
Maintaining accurate lineage ensures the integrity of the family structure. Falsely claiming parentage or altering family relationships can create confusion and lead to injustice in matters like inheritance, family obligations, and the distribution of wealth.
Religious and moral truthfulness:
Islam places high importance on truthfulness and honesty. Falsifying lineage goes against these moral values, as it involves a lie about the most fundamental aspect of human relationships—family ties.
Spiritual consequences:
The hadith warns that such a grave sin can sever one's spiritual connection with Allah, which is a central concern in Islam. Being cut off from Allah’s mercy and forgiveness is a severe punishment, which could have eternal consequences in the Hereafter, such as being deprived of Paradise.
Context of the Hadith:
The situation of a woman bringing a child into a family:
The hadith addresses a scenario where a woman might be involved in misrepresenting the lineage of a child, such as through adoption or any other means that could confuse or falsely claim parentage. This could happen due to various reasons, such as trying to secure a place in a family for a child born out of wedlock or to avoid certain legal consequences. However, Islam prohibits such acts because they compromise the integrity of both the family and the broader community.
Can anyone confirm it and show me if it is correct?

This is also found in this fatwa- https://www.islamweb.net/en/fatwa/406384/husband-abroad-for-3-years-and-once-he-arrived-wife-had-baby

Any discussion and comment is appreciated

So you've asked an AI and got an answer, what exactly don't you like in the given answer, we are not here to read and check AI answers.

@Medi1Saif you shall understand that as there was no other option available hence I was forced to resort to whatever is available. But I would like to have an answer from a knowledgeable person in this regard, i.e a real life person

@Medi1Saif I can't thank you enough for providing links to the hadith I could not find them even after searching on that web. Many many thanks
